# Human editable JSON-like or YAML-like program configuration in Java

Tags: java, configuration, hocon

Is there a Java library similar to libconfig for C++, where the config file is stored in a JSON-like format that can be edited by humans, and later read from the program?

I don't want to use Spring or any of the larger frameworks. What I'm looking for is a small, fast, self-contained library. I looked at `java.util.Properties`, but it doesn't seem to support hierarchical/nested config data.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think https://github.com/typesafehub/config is exactly what you are looking for. The format is called *HOCON* for *Human-Optimized Config Object Notation* and it a super-set of *JSON*.

[Examples of HOCON](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#examples-of-hocon):

*HOCON* that is also valid *JSON*:

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "bar" : 10,
        "baz" : 12
    }
}
```

HOCON also supports standard properties format, so the following is valid as well:

```
foo.bar=10
foo.baz=12
```

One of the features I find very useful is inheritance, this allows you to layer configurations. For instance a library would have a `reference.conf`, and the application using the library would have an `application.conf`. The settings in the `application.conf` will override the defaults in `reference.conf`.

[Standard Behavior](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior) for loading configs:

> The convenience method ConfigFactory.load() loads the following
>   (first-listed are higher priority):
>
> - system properties application.conf (all resources on classpath with
>     this name)
> - application.json (all resources on classpath with this
>     name)
> - application.properties (all resources on classpath with this
>     name)
> - reference.conf (all resources on classpath with this name)

Answer (score 4):

I found this [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config) example:

```
my.organization {
    project {
        name = "DeathStar"
        description = ${my.organization.project.name} "is a tool to take control over whole world. By world I mean couch, computer and fridge ;)"
    }
    team {
        members = [
            "Aneta"
            "Kamil"
            "Lukasz"
            "Marcin"
        ]
    }
}
my.organization.team.avgAge = 26
```

to read values:

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
config.getString("my.organization.project.name")  // => DeathStar
config.getString("my.organization.project.description") // => DeathStar is a tool to take control over whole world. By world I mean couch, computer and fridge ;)
config.getInt("my.organization.team.avgAge") // => 26
config.getStringList("my.organization.team.members") // => [Aneta, Kamil, Lukasz, Marcin]
```

*Reference*: [marcinkubala.wordpress.com](http://marcinkubala.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/typesace-config-hocon/)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Commons Configuration API](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/) and [Constretto](http://constretto.jira.com/wiki/display/CC/Introduction) seem to be somewhat popular and support multiple formats (no JSON mentioned, though). I've personally never tried either, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Java library to handle JSON files if that's what you're looking for:

http://www.json.org/java/index.html

Check out other tools on the main page:

http://json.org/

Comment: Well, I need something were I don't have to worry about parsing the file at all. All I should do is initialize with file name, and then read the keys off using a single command.

Comment: That's exactly what you need so. Maybe not a single command, but near enough to that.